# Is there a limit how many character can be send over udp/snmp?

Tags: c, snmp

I'm trying to send a string from server to client via UDP/SNMP. However, if I copy a string with length `86` to pdu `packet->value_value` everything works fine, I get the string on client side. If I add just one char more to the string, length is now `87`, the packet can not deliver to the client. The packet size raise correctly. Is there a limit how many char can be send? My packet is smaller than 1500.

This code snippet shows how I copy the string to `packet->value_value`

```
value_value = "asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd as";
printf("String length: %d\n",strlen(value_value)); // 86 OK, 87or greater NOK
packet->value_length = strlen(value_value);
packet->value_value = malloc(packet->value_length);
strcpy(packet->value_value, value_value);
```

For some information, here a terminal output with some more informations about packet lengths

Output with string length `86`

```
src/agent.c:69:parse_request(): Input length=43
src/agent.c:116:perform_snmp_request(): OID is: 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
String length: 86
src/mibservice.c:90:snmpget(): packet->value_type=04
src/mibservice.c:91:snmpget(): packet->value_length=56
src/mibservice.c:93:snmpget(): packet->value_value=61
...
src/mibservice.c:93:snmpget(): packet->value_value=73
src/mibservice.c:95:snmpget(): Before packet->length=41
src/mibservice.c:97:snmpget(): After packet->length=127
src/mibservice.c:99:snmpget(): Before packet->pdu_length=28
src/mibservice.c:101:snmpget(): After packet->pdu_length=114
src/mibservice.c:103:snmpget(): Before packet->variablebindings_length=14
src/mibservice.c:105:snmpget(): After packet->variablebindings_length=100
src/mibservice.c:107:snmpget(): Before packet->varbind_length=12
src/mibservice.c:109:snmpget(): After packet->varbind_length=98
src/agent.c:96:create_response(): Output length=129
```

Output with string length `87`

```
src/agent.c:69:parse_request(): Input length=43
src/agent.c:116:perform_snmp_request(): OID is: 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
String length: 87
src/mibservice.c:90:snmpget(): packet->value_type=04
src/mibservice.c:91:snmpget(): packet->value_length=57
src/mibservice.c:93:snmpget(): packet->value_value=61
...
src/mibservice.c:93:snmpget(): packet->value_value=64
src/mibservice.c:95:snmpget(): Before packet->length=41
src/mibservice.c:97:snmpget(): After packet->length=128
src/mibservice.c:99:snmpget(): Before packet->pdu_length=28
src/mibservice.c:101:snmpget(): After packet->pdu_length=115
src/mibservice.c:103:snmpget(): Before packet->variablebindings_length=14
src/mibservice.c:105:snmpget(): After packet->variablebindings_length=101
src/mibservice.c:107:snmpget(): Before packet->varbind_length=12
src/mibservice.c:109:snmpget(): After packet->varbind_length=99
src/agent.c:96:create_response(): Output length=130
```

**Update**
Here is a runnable example about my problem. Packet `out_buf_0` represent a valid SNMP packet and can send via UDP. Packet `out_buf_1` is the same packet like `out_buf_0` with one character more at the end `0x64`. Further, I raised all length + 1 because of the additional character. Why is `out_buf_1` not a valid SNMP packet/why can it not send via UDP? Note: The SNMP request can not display in terminal because the `request id` from client is different from `out_buf_0` and `out_buf_1`, take a look in wireshark to see the request/response.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MESSAGE_MAX_LEN  1500 /* MTU, IEEE Std 802.3TM-2015 */
#define PORT 161 /* RFC 1157 */

int out_buf_0_len = 129; /* 0x7f + 2 */
char out_buf_0[] = {
0x30, /* SNMP Packet start */
0x7f, /* SNMP Packet length */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /* Version */
0x04, 0x06, 0x70, 0x75, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x63, /* Community*/
0xa2, /* GetResponsePDU */
0x72, /* GetResponsePDU Length */
0x02, 0x04, 0x2c, 0x80, 0x7e, 0x2f, /* Request id */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /*Error status */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /*Error index */
0x30, /* Varbind list start */
0x64, /* Varbind list length*/
0x30, /* Varbind value start */
0x62, /* Varbind value length */
0x06, 0x08, 0x2b, 0x06, 0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, /* OID */
0x04,  /* Value start, type octet-string*/
0x56, /* Value length */
0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, /* Value */
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73 };

int out_buf_1_len = 130; /* 0x80 + 2 */
char out_buf_1[] = {
0x30, /* SNMP Packet start */
0x80, /* SNMP Packet length */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /* Version */
0x04, 0x06, 0x70, 0x75, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x63, /* Community*/
0xa2, /* GetResponsePDU */
0x73, /* GetResponsePDU Length */
0x02, 0x04, 0x2c, 0x80, 0x7e, 0x2f, /* Request id */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /*Error status */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /*Error index */
0x30, /* Varbind list start */
0x65, /* Varbind list length*/
0x30, /* Varbind value start */
0x63, /* Varbind value length */
0x06, 0x08, 0x2b, 0x06, 0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, /* OID */
0x04,  /* Value start, type octet-string*/
0x57, /* Value length */
0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, /* Value */
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64 };

int my_socket;
struct sockaddr_in remote_addr;
int socket_create()
{
    printf("Create socket\n");
    struct sockaddr_in socket_addr;
    if ((my_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot create socket. Exit.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    memset((char *)&socket_addr, 0, sizeof(socket_addr));
    socket_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    socket_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if (bind(my_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&socket_addr, sizeof(socket_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Bind failed. Exit.\n");
        return - 1;
    }
    printf("Listen on: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(socket_addr.sin_addr), PORT);
    return 0;
}

socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(remote_addr);
void socket_listen(char *in_buf)
{
    int  recv_len; /* Bytes received */
    int  nbyt; /* Bytes count */
    char *out_buf[MESSAGE_MAX_LEN];
    int  out_len = 0;

    for (;;) { /* Receive snmp message from snmp manager */
        recv_len = recvfrom(my_socket, in_buf, MESSAGE_MAX_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, &addr_len);
        if (recv_len > 0)
            if (sendto(my_socket, out_buf_1, out_buf_1_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, addr_len) < 0)
                printf("Cannot send data to destination.\n");
    }
}

/* Disable SNMP on local machine. # systemctl stop snmpd 
 * Execute main(): gcc <filename>.c && ./a.out
 * Run SNMP Request: $ snmpget -v 1 -c public 0.0.0.0:161 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
 */
char in_buf[MESSAGE_MAX_LEN];
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (socket_create() == -1)
        exit(2);
    socket_listen(in_buf);
}
```

The whole frame length including my SNMPv1 packet `out_buf_0` is 1368 bits, `out_buf_1` should 1376 bits.

Comment: Off by 1? `malloc(packet->value_length + 1);` add 1 before `strcpy` for the `NUL` terminator. Or perhaps `packet->value_length = strlen(value_value) + 1;` instead.

Comment: @WeatherVane the problem is the same and if I add +1 the value length is wrong.

Comment: Your program overran the memory allocation and caused UB.

Comment: to answer the title of the question, the length field in the UDP header is an unsigned 16 bit field that contains the length of the header plus the length of the message in bytes. Theoretically this is 65,535 bytes. In reality the MTU size is going to be your limiting factor,, this is generally 1500 bytes. If you're doing everything on loopback then MTU size doesn't matter (at least on my linux system). Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure). But there should be no problems sending a character string 87 long. (assuming byte=8 bits)

Comment: @WeatherVane what can I do now. what is UB?

Comment: [Undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), but if you corrected that error, there is a different problem. You need to decide if the `NUL` terminator to the string is a part of the packet data. If not, use `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`.

Comment: If the datagram is 1500<datagram<64k will the stack not just fragment the packet as 'normal', so allowing the datagram to be sent, but increasing the chance of a failed reassembly and so dropped datagram?

Comment: @MartinJames My (hardly exhaustive) experience has been that sending UDP packets larger than the MTU results in dropped data. Wireshark capture simply shows "fragmented packet" and the amount of received data is far smaller than expected. Perhaps there are systems with network stacks that will do this reassembly for you, but mine don't seem to have them. Given the lightweight-as-possible nature of UDP I'd be surprised to learn such a thing exists.

Comment: off by 1 is not needed, see my update :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SNMP packet length `0x80` is wrong, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871813/why-is-my-snmp-packet-not-valid)

> The ASN.1 length field of 0x80 is wrong. The decoder sees the first
>   two octets of your packet are 0x30 0x80 and determines from that 0x80
>   that there should be no more octets following. And yet there are more
>   octets, so it is an invalid encoding and further not a valid SNMP
>   message. The 0x80 here does not mean 128 octets for content as you
>   intend, it means your length field is 0x80 & ~0x80 == 0 octets long
>   following this octet. Instead, 0x81 would mean your length field is
>   0x81 & ~0x80 == 1 following octets, and that following 0x80 octet
>   would indicate a content length of 128.

Thats how the SNMP packet should look like,

```
char out_buf_1[] = {
0x30, /* SNMP Packet start */
0x81, 0x80, /* SNMP Packet length */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /* Version */
0x04, 0x06, 0x70, 0x75, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x63, /* Community*/
0xa2, /* GetResponsePDU */
0x73, /* GetResponsePDU Length */
0x02, 0x04, 0x2c, 0x80, 0x7e, 0x2f, /* Request id */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /*Error status */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /*Error index */
0x30, /* Varbind list start */
0x65, /* Varbind list length*/
0x30, /* Varbind value start */
0x63, /* Varbind value length */
0x06, 0x08, 0x2b, 0x06, 0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, /* OID */
0x04,  /* Value start, type octet-string*/
0x57, /* Value length */
0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, /* Value */
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64 };
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointer out in the comments, strcpy is evil and should never be used for anything. Your malloc actually allocated an array smaller than your original array because you did not take into account the trailing null. when you used strcpy you wrote past the end of the allocated array with the trailing null.

Since you didn't include code related to packet structure I don't know how it is being used but if any code after this expects C null terminated strings it probable won't work as expected.

Comment: `strcpy` is **not** evil anymore than any other library function is evil. (`strncpy` does have the inefficiency of zeroing all unused space). The issue is proper accounting for all characters required, including the *nul-terminating* character. (which is what distinguishes a *C-string* from a *character array*). Without a *nul-terminating* character, `strcpy` will happily continue off onto the stack copying values until the first stray `0` is encountered. With a proper *nul-terminated* string `strcpy` is perfectly fine.