# Why is my snmp packet not valid

Tags: c, networking, snmp

I wrote a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847389/is-there-a-limit-how-many-character-can-be-send-over-udp-snmp) but did not get an answer which solve my problem, so I write the question again on stackoverflow and hope that somebody can help me.

Here is a runnable example about my problem. Packet `out_buf_0` represent a valid SNMP packet and can send via UDP. Packet `out_buf_1` is the same packet like `out_buf_0` with one character more at the end `0x64`. Further, I raised all length + 1 because of the additional character. **Why is out_buf_1 not a valid SNMPv1 packet/why can it not send via UDP?** Note: The SNMP request can not display in terminal because the request id from client is different from `out_buf_0` and `out_buf_1`, take a look in wireshark to see the request/response. The whole frame length including my SNMPv1 packet `out_buf_0` is 1368 bits, `out_buf_1` should 1376 bits.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MESSAGE_MAX_LEN  1500 /* MTU, IEEE Std 802.3TM-2015 */
#define PORT 161 /* RFC 1157 */

int out_buf_0_len = 129; /* 0x7f + 2 */
char out_buf_0[] = {
0x30, /* SNMP Packet start */
0x7f, /* SNMP Packet length */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /* Version */
0x04, 0x06, 0x70, 0x75, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x63, /* Community*/
0xa2, /* GetResponsePDU */
0x72, /* GetResponsePDU Length */
0x02, 0x04, 0x2c, 0x80, 0x7e, 0x2f, /* Request id */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /*Error status */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /*Error index */
0x30, /* Varbind list start */
0x64, /* Varbind list length*/
0x30, /* Varbind value start */
0x62, /* Varbind value length */
0x06, 0x08, 0x2b, 0x06, 0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, /* OID */
0x04,  /* Value start, type octet-string*/
0x56, /* Value length */
0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, /* Value */
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73 };

int out_buf_1_len = 130; /* 0x80 + 2 */
char out_buf_1[] = {
0x30, /* SNMP Packet start */
0x80, /* SNMP Packet length */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /* Version */
0x04, 0x06, 0x70, 0x75, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x63, /* Community*/
0xa2, /* GetResponsePDU */
0x73, /* GetResponsePDU Length */
0x02, 0x04, 0x2c, 0x80, 0x7e, 0x2f, /* Request id */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /*Error status */
0x02, 0x01, 0x00, /*Error index */
0x30, /* Varbind list start */
0x65, /* Varbind list length*/
0x30, /* Varbind value start */
0x63, /* Varbind value length */
0x06, 0x08, 0x2b, 0x06, 0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, /* OID */
0x04,  /* Value start, type octet-string*/
0x57, /* Value length */
0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, /* Value */
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x20, 0x61,
0x73, 0x64 };

int my_socket;
struct sockaddr_in remote_addr;
int socket_create()
{
    printf("Create socket\n");
    struct sockaddr_in socket_addr;
    if ((my_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot create socket. Exit.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    memset((char *)&socket_addr, 0, sizeof(socket_addr));
    socket_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    socket_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if (bind(my_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&socket_addr, sizeof(socket_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Bind failed. Exit.\n");
        return - 1;
    }
    printf("Listen on: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(socket_addr.sin_addr), PORT);
    return 0;
}

socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(remote_addr);
void socket_listen(char *in_buf)
{
    int  recv_len; /* Bytes received */
    int  nbyt; /* Bytes count */
    char *out_buf[MESSAGE_MAX_LEN];
    int  out_len = 0;

    for (;;) { /* Receive snmp message from snmp manager */
        recv_len = recvfrom(my_socket, in_buf, MESSAGE_MAX_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, &addr_len);
        if (recv_len > 0)
            if (sendto(my_socket, out_buf_1, out_buf_1_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, addr_len) < 0)
                printf("Cannot send data to destination.\n");
    }
}

/* Disable SNMP on local machine. # systemctl stop snmpd 
 * Execute main(): gcc <filename>.c && ./a.out
 * Run SNMP Request: $ snmpget -v 1 -c public 0.0.0.0:161 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
 */
char in_buf[MESSAGE_MAX_LEN];
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (socket_create() == -1)
        exit(2);
    socket_listen(in_buf);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under ASN.1 Basic Encoding Rules (BER), an ASN.1 encoding consists of a single octet tag value, one or more length octets, and zero or more content octets. The length part of an encoding takes one of two forms: a single-octet form or a multi-octet form. The high order bit indicates which form the length field takes: unset is a single-octet length, in which the single octet (of range 00..7F) indicates the content length, and set is a multi-octet length (80..FF), in which the remaining bits of the first octet specify how many following octets comprise the actual length of contents.

```
int out_buf_1_len = 130; /* 0x80 + 2 */
char out_buf_1[] = {
0x30, /* SNMP Packet start */
0x80, /* SNMP Packet length */
...
```

What you have here is a length octet of `0x80`, which indicates it is a multi-byte length field where the length of the length field itself is 0, so the length of expected contents is 0. What you would want at this point is `0x81` (the 0x80 bit here indicating multi-byte length, and the 0x01 part here indicating one octet follows for content length) followed by a `0x80` octet (indicating your length of contents) before the rest of your contents.

I stopped analyzing there.

Comment: I dont get what you mean, could you please analyze further? Do you want to say that the SNMP packet length of `0x80` is wrong?

Comment: I changed `0x80` to `0x81` and it sends successfully but can not parse as SNMP packet. Can you write down the correct SNMP Packet  please?

Comment: I mean the ASN.1 length field of 0x80 is wrong. The decoder sees the first two octets of your packet are 0x30 0x80 and determines from that 0x80 that there should be no more octets following. And yet there are more octets, so it is an invalid encoding and further not a valid SNMP message. The 0x80 here does not mean 128 octets for content as you intend, it means your length field is `0x80 & ~0x80 == 0` octets long following this octet. Instead, `0x81` would mean your length field is `0x81 & ~0x80 == 1` following octets, and *that* following `0x80` octet would indicate a content length of 128.

Comment: I get it, i wrote `0x30, /* SNMP Packet start */
0x81, 0x80, /* SNMP Packet length */ ...` and extend the `out_buf_1_len`

Comment: `0x30, /* SNMP Packet start */ 0x81, 0x80, /* SNMP Packet length */ ...` and `out_buf_1_len = 131` and it's still not working?

Comment: Its working, I can see the SNMP Response in Wireshark, but not in my agent because the implementation of this specific rule needs some time. My problem is solved, thank you very much. Are there any other rules to consider?